# Как вывести поле ACF в файле functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

В шаблоне имеется следующий код, выводящий 6 последних новостей:

```
<div class="index-container2 mob-none">
    <?
    $pages = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => 6,
        'category_name' => 'glavnaya',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
    ));
    ?>
    <?
    $isPush = false;
    foreach ($pages as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>

        <?
        $dd = get_the_date('d.m');
        $image = get_field('изображение');
        $size = get_field('размер_блока_в_новостях');
        $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/proc-grey.png';
        //$bg_color = '#bba68f';
        $border_grey = '';

        if ($size == 'Большая ширина') $size = 'news-body_big';
        else $size = 'news-body_standart';

        //Определяем цвет фона
        $temp_color = get_field('шаблон_цвета');
        $bg_color = get_field('цвет_фона');

        if (!$bg_color) {
            if ($temp_color == "Серый") $bg_color = "#f1f0f0";
            else if ($temp_color == "Белый") $bg_color = "#ffffff";
            else if ($temp_color == "Коричневый") $bg_color = "#bba68f";
            else $bg_color = "#ffffff";
        }


        //определяем изображение
        $image_big = get_field('изображение_новости');
        $icon = get_field('иконка');
        $temp_img = get_field('шаблон_для_изображения');
        if ($image_big) {
            $bottom_img = '';
        } else if ($icon) {
            $bottom_img = $icon['url'];
        } else if ($temp_img) {
            if ($temp_img == "Процент") {
                if ($temp_color == "Серый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/proc-braun.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Белый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/proc-grey.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Коричневый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/proc-white.png';
            } else if ($temp_img == "Подарок") {
                if ($temp_color == "Серый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/present-braun.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Белый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/present-grey.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Коричневый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/present-white.png';
            } else if ($temp_img == "Подарок") {
                if ($temp_color == "Серый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/pack-braun.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Белый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/pack-grey.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Коричневый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/pack-white.png';
            }
        }
        //делаем рамку, если фон белый и нет картинки
        if ($bg_color == '#ffffff' && $bottom_img !== '') {
            $border_grey = ';border: 1.5px solid #f1f0f0;';
        }


        ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="news-body <?php echo $size ?>"
           style="background-color: <?php echo $bg_color;
           echo $border_grey; ?>;">
            <? /*<div class="name"><?php the_field('заголовок'); ?></div>
                  <div class="desc"><?php the_field('описание'); ?></div>
                  <div class="img"><?php if ($bottom_img != '') { ?><img src="<?php echo $bottom_img ?>"  alt=""><?php } ?></div>*/ ?>
            <div class="img2"><?php if ($image_big) { ?><img src="<?php echo $image_big['url']; ?>"
                                                             alt=""><?php } ?></div>
        </a>
        <?
        $isPush = !$isPush;
    } ?>

    <? wp_reset_query();
    ?>
    <div class="button-block">
        <button class="load-news" type="button" data-page="1">Ещё новости</button>
    </div>
```

Пытаюсь теперь сделать подгрузку следующих 6 новостей через AJAX, для этого зарегистрировал функцию-обработчик и в ней продублировал вышеописанный код:

```
    function load_more_news()
{
    $args = $_POST;
    $args['page']++;
    $args['numberposts'] = 6;
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    $args['post_type'] = 'post';
    $pages = get_posts($args);
    $isPush = false;
    foreach ($pages as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $dd = get_the_date('d.m');
        $image = get_field('изображение');
        var_dump($post);
        $size = get_field('размер_блока_в_новостях');
        $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/proc-grey.png';
        //$bg_color = '#bba68f';
        $border_grey = '';

        if ($size == 'Большая ширина') $size = 'news-body_big';
        else $size = 'news-body_standart';

        //Определяем цвет фона
        $temp_color = get_field('шаблон_цвета');
        $bg_color = get_field('цвет_фона');

        if (!$bg_color) {
            if ($temp_color == "Серый") $bg_color = "#f1f0f0";
            else if ($temp_color == "Белый") $bg_color = "#ffffff";
            else if ($temp_color == "Коричневый") $bg_color = "#bba68f";
            else $bg_color = "#ffffff";
        }


        //определяем изображение
        $image_big = get_field('изображение_новости');
        $icon = get_field('иконка');
        $temp_img = get_field('шаблон_для_изображения');
        if ($image_big) {
            $bottom_img = '';
        } else if ($icon) {
            $bottom_img = $icon['url'];
        } else if ($temp_img) {
            if ($temp_img == "Процент") {
                if ($temp_color == "Серый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/proc-braun.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Белый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/proc-grey.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Коричневый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/proc-white.png';
            } else if ($temp_img == "Подарок") {
                if ($temp_color == "Серый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/present-braun.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Белый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/present-grey.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Коричневый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/present-white.png';
            } else if ($temp_img == "Подарок") {
                if ($temp_color == "Серый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/pack-braun.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Белый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/pack-grey.png';
                else if ($temp_color == "Коричневый") $bottom_img = '' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/pack-white.png';
            }
        }
        //делаем рамку, если фон белый и нет картинки
        if ($bg_color == '#ffffff' && $bottom_img !== '') {
            $border_grey = ';border: 1.5px solid #f1f0f0;';
        }


        ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="news-body <?php echo $size ?>"
           style="background-color: <?php echo $bg_color;
           echo $border_grey; ?>;">
            <? /*<div class="name"><?php the_field('заголовок'); ?></div>
                      <div class="desc"><?php the_field('описание'); ?></div>
                      <div class="img"><?php if ($bottom_img != '') { ?><img src="<?php echo $bottom_img ?>"  alt=""><?php } ?></div>*/ ?>
            <div class="img2"><?php if ($image_big) { ?><img src="<?php echo $image_big['url']; ?>"
                                                             alt=""><?php } ?></div>
        </a>
        <?
        $isPush = !$isPush;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_die();
}
```

Но при нажатии кнопки подгрузки на экран выводятся только 6 обёрток, ни картинок, ни текста в них не появляется.

Попытки поиска готового решения ничего не дали - везде требуют оборачивания `get_field()` в цикл, что у меня уже сделано.

Судя по всему, в `functions.php` нужно что-то подключить для работы ACF. Но что?

Comment: Что выведет `var_dump($image_big)` перед `<a ...` ?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, `bool(false)`

Comment: Почитайте о различии `page` и `paged`: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-paginatsii

Comment: @KAGGDesign, исправил, но это не помогло, к тому же через AJAX передаётся именно `paged`

Answer (score 0):

Помогло явное указание ID поста:

```
$image_big = get_field('изображение_новости', $post->ID);
```

Почему он не определился сам, правда, остаётся непонятным.